# VBA Word Why doesn't .BaseStyle stay capitalized?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word VBA, I use the `.BaseStyle` method to set the base style of a new text style. In the object viewer and in Intellisense, the method name is capitalized as `.BaseStyle`. But when I actually use it in my code (which works properly), VBA changes the name to lowercase `.basestyle`. Usually a lowercase method name indicates a coding mistake, but in this case, everything works properly.

It's very strange. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you

```
Dim mystyle as Style
mystyle.basestyle = "Heading 1"
OR
mystyle.basestyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
```

Comment: You probably have `Dim basestyle As Foo` somewhere.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your immediate response! I have carefully searched for "Dim basestyle" (case insensitive, in the current project) and found no instances. I also seeded a "dim basestyle" declaration in a random VBA module after my search to see if a second search would find it. It did. I removed the seed. I quit all Office 365 programs and rebooted them to ensure all objects were flushed. I started up a different document (same vba modules), and the problem remained.  If I had made a `Dim basestyle as Style` declaration in the past, how could I fix the problem?

Comment: You can "trick" it by just typing `Dim BaseStyle` then deleting it.

Comment: Yay! You and @Vityata nailed it! Thank you so much - I _NEVER_ would have found that problem or solution. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as an answer...

Comment: @Comintern - now looking at your profile I somehow understand how I came up with mine. :D And I thought I was being original :)

Comment: @Vityata Apparenlty great minds think alike. ;-)

Comment: @Comintern - I guess I have seen it some time ago and when I was editing the profile it somehow came up ... Will change it:)

Comment: I say this old saying with all kindness and humor... "Great minds think alike, but fools seldom differ..."  I think both you guys are great. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kevin - no problem :) In general, you may go through the answers of Comintern https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern and vote for not more than 2, which you think that are helpful. (More than 2 is not a good idea, they would be probably considered spam-voting). This is what I usually do, when I consider that a post or comment has helped me. It is not a good practice, but not a bad one as well :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know that I could read through a person's answers as a method to find a new learning resource! Sounds like a great idea. I will do that, thank you.

Comment: @Kevin - it is a nice learning resource indeed. As you are into IOS, take a look into the ranking here - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/topusers - and check once per week answers of those users. You would probably learn some interesting stuff.

Comment: @Vityata - Thank you so much again! Camping on the flow of good answers sounds like a great way to learn!